# Mutable variable is accessible from closure inside angular services

Tags: javascript, angularjs, closures

I'm working with angular ui grid library and trying to populate custom dropdown filter. This filter can be applied only for specific columns that's why I have wrote for loop that to get an access to columns dynamically. For each specific column I send a request to api thru my angular services that to get values for my filter, and if response successful I compare each columns property id with returned data id, and then populate filter value.

The problem appears inside of `then` function, the IDE shows me the warning

> mutable variable is accessible from closure

and inside of `then` function nothing works.

I have read multiple topics here and found out that I have to execute self-invoke function, but it doesn't work as well.

So where is my mistake? thanks in advance

code

```
 for (var i = 0; i <  $scope.columns.length; i++) {

                        // ===== rebuild columns tree =====

                        var execute_ids = [];

                        angular.forEach($scope.columns[i].property, function(){                             
                           if ($scope.columns[i].property.strict === true){

                                if(execute_ids.indexOf($scope.columns[i].property.propertyTypeId) === -1){
                                    execute_ids.push($scope.columns[i].property.propertyTypeId);

                                    lovServices.customPropFilterValue(execute_ids)
                                        .then(function (response) {
                                            (function () {
                                            if (response.id == $scope.columns[i].property.propertyTypeId){

                                                $scope.filter.push({
                                                    value: data.value,
                                                    label: data.value
                                                });

                                                 $scope.columns[i].filter = {
                                                    type: uiGridConstants.filter.SELECT,
                                                    condition: uiGridConstants.filter.EXACT,
                                                    selectOptions: $scope.filter
                                                };
                                            }
                                            })()
                                        });
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    }
```

the original part of code

```
lovServices.customPropFilterValue(execute_ids)
                                        .then(function (response) {
                                            if (response.id == $scope.columns[i].property.propertyTypeId){

                                                $scope.filter.push({
                                                    value: response.value,
                                                    label: response.value
                                                });

                                                $scope.columns[i].filter = {
                                                    type: uiGridConstants.filter.SELECT,
                                                    condition: uiGridConstants.filter.EXACT,
                                                    selectOptions: $scope.filter
                                                };
                                            }
                                        });
```

**EDIT**

I used solution provided by @JuanTonina and the warning is gone, but it appeared another one problem. The `i` inside of `then` function returns wrong value

```
 (function (i) { /* note that the lovServices call is INSIDE the IIFE*/

            console.log($scope.columns[i].property.propertyTypeId)

 // this console log returns correct ids (120, 123, 194)

            lovServices.customPropFilterValue(execute_ids)
                .then(function (response) {

                    console.log($scope.columns[i].property.propertyTypeId)

 // this console log returns wrong ids (120, undefined, 114)

                    if (response.id == $scope.columns[i].property.propertyTypeId) {

                        $scope.filter.push({
                            value: data.value,
                            label: data.value
                        });

                        $scope.columns[i].filter = {
                            type: uiGridConstants.filter.SELECT,
                            condition: uiGridConstants.filter.EXACT,
                            selectOptions: $scope.filter
                        };
                    }
                });
        })(i)
```

Comment: You need to pass `i` as a parameter of the IIFE

`(function (i) {//code})(i)`

Comment: @JuanTonina still nothing `lovServices.customPropFilterValue(execute_ids)
.then(function (response) {
 (function (i) {
//my ocde 
      })(i);
 });`

Comment: Sorry, just noted that your IIFE only wraps the `.then` part. Your code should look like this:

`for(var i...){ (function(i){//the entire content of the loop})(i)}`

The reason for this is that your variable `i` is changing before being used on the callback. As a side note, if you are using es6, doing `for( let i = 0...)` also solves the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm adding this as an answer since the comments are not enough to show what I mean.

Your code should look like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.columns.length; i++) {

// ===== rebuild columns tree =====

var execute_ids = [];

angular.forEach($scope.columns[i].property, function () {
    if ($scope.columns[i].property.strict === true) {

        if (execute_ids.indexOf($scope.columns[i].property.propertyTypeId) === -1) {
            execute_ids.push($scope.columns[i].property.propertyTypeId);

            (function (i) { /* note that the lovServices call is INSIDE the IIFE*/
                lovServices.customPropFilterValue(execute_ids)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        if (response.id == $scope.columns[i].property.propertyTypeId) {

                            $scope.filter.push({
                                value: data.value,
                                label: data.value
                            });

                            $scope.columns[i].filter = {
                                type: uiGridConstants.filter.SELECT,
                                condition: uiGridConstants.filter.EXACT,
                                selectOptions: $scope.filter
                            };
                        }
                    });
            })(i)
        }
    }
});

}
```

The reason for this is that your variable `i` is changing before being used on the callback. As a side note, if you are using es6, doing for`( let i = 0;...)` also solves the problem

Comment: Could you try logging `i` instead of `console.log($scope.columns[i].property.propertyTypeId)` and check if `i` is in fact wrong? It looks like you are doing some operations over `$scope.columns`, so it might be a completely different issue

Comment: yeah you are right, after I've got values I pushed one more additional column and it has changed the order of columns, so now it is good, thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be related because you have a Immediately-Invoked Function Expression, or IIFE for short. And  It is executed immediately after it’s created.

Removing from inside your `.then()` method and it should works fine.

```
(function () {

})();
```

Comment: This how I did before and it didn't work 
`.then(function (response) {
    if (response.id == $scope.columns[i].property.propertyTypeId){`

Comment: this is possible a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34689730/wait-for-promises-inside-of-a-angular-foreach-loop that solution seems to be the right one.